# CentOS 5.10 TCP Sequence Number

Tags: tcp, centos5, linux-kernel

We have done a security check on a server and its come back with

Linux Kernel TCP Sequence Number Generation Security Weakness. We are looking to correct this being flagged up on the check

We are using CentOS 5.10 with kernel 2.6.18-371.9.1.el5

Comment: If your security check doesn't tell you more about the vulnerabilities it finds, it's time to switch to a different vendor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [CVE-2011-3188](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/49289/info) which has been fixed since the RedHat kernel [2.6.18-274.7.1.el5](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2011-1386.html).
So either that server isn't running the kernel you mention (installed but not rebooted?), it tested the wrong system (some transparent device between the check and the server?) or it is a false positive (unsure why).

Comment: Thanks for the info will get the vendor to check the server again. The server has been rebooted since the kernel updated.